# Possible to use local and icloud notes in OSX Mavericks Notes.app?

Tags: macos, icloud, notes.app

I just had a situation arise where I have a single note that has a sensitive password in it, that I don't want shared in the cloud.  I would like it to only be "On My Mac", which I recall being able to do in the past.

But now it seems that there is no way to store local notes if you also use iCloud notes.  I definitely use lots of iCloud notes, I just want this one note to be stored locally.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 2):

From the Menubar select *Notes > Preferences* `⌘,`

Enable *Enable the On My Mac account* and close.

You may need to *View > Show Folders*

You can now drag notes between the local and iCloud folders

Comment: There is no preferences menu item.

Comment: Ahh, your using Mavericks. I don't have an active system with that. Try this. Sign out of iCloud. Delete all notes when it asks. Don't worry they will all still be in the cloud. Now create a new note on the Mac. There should be some kind of view option/side-bar so you can see it has been saved to the Mac. Sign back into iCloud. If it asked to *merge* click *don't/cancel*. You should now have local Mac notes, and iCloud notes.

Comment: I already tried that twice, same result both times… No change, no local folder on my Mac after turning iCloud back on

Comment: Try creating a new system user to test with, there may be some cache or config persisting that is causing you not to see the local notes. Alternatively, if you only have a few private notes, save them to a local non-syncing keychain instead.

Comment: Not sure what a "local non syncing keychain" is, but yes it's just a single note.  Frankly I'm probably better off just saving it as a text file somewhere as this is proving to be too much to ask of the old Notes apparently, nor have I found an alternative free equivalent solution.

Comment: Applications > Utilities > Keychan. Select your **login** keychain, then, File > New Secure Note Item. This will allow you to create a note that is locked with your login password. You could also File > New Keychain to setup a seperate *vault* for similar type of notes with it's own password.